# Update Symfoy 2 to newer version

Tags: php, windows, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.0.9 to build a new web site. Yesterday the newer version 2.0.10 went out and I need to update my local project (windows 7) to that version. I saw that using linux the process of update is easy because you just need to run a command and everything works out of the box but in windows there is no written solution. How should I update? Simply overwriting files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the same procedure that is valid for linux is valid for windows as well. The bin/vendors script (the one that updates vendor folders) is actually a PHP script, so you can run it under windows in the same way you run the app/console script.

Comment: you are right but it seems that I need git installed to run that command. Is there any other method?

Comment: Manual update is the only other viable option: remove the vendors, reinstall them using the latest version and check if you need to update parts of your config.

Comment: can I safely overwrite all the files?

Comment: How safely depends on changes between the two versions of Symfony you are considering. Updating may break something in configuration or in some class you may use, refer to symfony's changelog to get some hints and if you have one use your test suite to detect regressions.